# Changing Pull Switch Ceiling Fan with Faulty Capacitor to Remote

Tags: ceiling-fan

The capacitor of my pull switch ceiling fan (with light) is faulty (the medium speed not working). If I changed from pull switch to remote, do I still need to replace the faulty capacitor? Can I connect the wires from the remote receiver directly to the fan motor wires?[image: Image of pull switch and capacitors of ceiling fan. The black wire (2 wires wrap in black) is for light]

Regards, Eng Hup.

Comment: Not quite sure what you're asking.  The capacitor is bad so replace it and that's all right? All your other questions aren't clear.

Comment: If this is a typical fan motor, the capacitor is part of the circuit that makes the fan reliably start in a particular direction. You probably do want to replace it, if you know it's bad.

Answer (score 1):

If you install a remote control module, it will control the speed of the fan. Which means, there will be no need for the pull switch. So yes, you can install a remote module instead of fixing the medium speed.

Install the remote module, put the pull switch in high, and enjoy.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Since the remote control module control the speed of the fan, it is possible to do away with the pull switch and the 2 capacitors and connect the wires from the remote receiver to the wires from the capacitors to the fan? This will avoid the problems when either the pull switch or the other capacitor become faulty.

Comment: @EngHupNg do you have a schematic for the fan?

Comment: No. I do not have a schematic for the fan and also did not manage to open the enclosure of the fan motor to view the connection of the two wires from the capacitors.